# Help with using JSON object inside PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, json

I am (trying) to build a web app, first one :)
I need to call a JSON object though, and I am using a simple search form to get a word that I will append to the call, but I need PHP to handle the object when it is returned. How can I do this?
Basically I had the form submit calling a function that, ideally, would go get the object and do what it needs to, then return the results formatted how I want. Does that make sense even?
Thank you!

Comment: So you are having the form go get some data formatted as JSON and then act on that data?  Sry, confused by question

Comment: I need the form just to get the user search string so I can call a JSON object. But when it is returned, I need it to be handled by my PHP function. So I was seeing if there is a way to pass the string into PHP, and then call the JSON object from within the PHP function...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP 5.x has some built in functions: [json_decode()](http://www.php.net/json_decode) and [json_encode()](http://www.php.net/json_encode). They are worth looking into and should answer your question. If you have less then PHP 5.x the user comments at both of those pages should have alternatives to use in it's place.

Comment: Yeah saw this :)  I am going to read those now, do they do what I am looking for? I have never used those functions before..

Comment: Read through them to determine. But yes, they should do what you described both in the question and the comment you posted.